# Asp.Net Identity SMS Verification token ever invalid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I try to verify a phone number with ASP.Net Identity.

Here is my code generation:

```
        public async Task<JsonResult> SendVerifyPhoneNumber()
    {
        var user = await this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.PhoneNumber))
            {
                if (!await this.UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
                {
                    string number = user.PhoneNumber;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number))
                    {
                        number = TelNumber.DecryptUserTelefon(number, ApplicationUser.AES_CRYPTO_KEY);
                    }
                    string code = await this.UserManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user.Id, number);
                    string text = string.Format(ResourcesLocal.Resources_Manage_Index.TelefoncodeNachrichtBestaetigen, code);
                    bool result = Helper.Services.SmsService.SendSMS(SmSWarteschlangeCon, number, text);
                }
            }

            return Json(true);
        }

        return Json(false);
    }
```

Where is my Code catch by input:

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> VerifyPhoneNumber(string code)
    {
        var user = await this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
        if (user != null)
        {
            string number = user.PhoneNumber;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number))
            {
                number = TelNumber.EncryptUserTelefon(number, ApplicationUser.AES_CRYPTO_KEY);
            }
            var result = await this.UserManager.ChangePhoneNumberAsync(
                        user.Id, number, code);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                user = await this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await this.SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                }
                return Json(true);
            }

        }
        return Json(false);
    }
```

But the result fail every time with "Invalid token" even if the code is the same and given within seconds...

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. How are you hosted? 2. Do you have `machinekey` specified in your `web.config`?

Comment: 1) What you mean with how I am hosted?
2) yes

Comment: Azure websites or other cloud provider?

Comment: Both not, just a normal IIS Webserver